# Disable timeout completely

Tags: java, android, xml

I would to know how to disable the timeout completely. I tried with

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, -1);
```

But it doens't work because shortly after the display turns off.

Comment: Are you looking for a `Wakelock` for your application, or to do this system-wide? You probably need system permissions to do it outside your app. Even in the case of `Wakelock`, you need some permission (can't think of the name at the moment).

Comment: The screen shall always remain switched only when my application is running but the timeout should be disabled altogether so that the screen never turn off, even when my application is not running.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep your screen awake, then you can do it by using this line in your Activity-

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: I want to disable the timeout everywhere, not just in my app

Comment: @Mario G., have you added this permission in manifest-

android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS